# What's the best way to extract the text in this case?

Tags: python, html, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find and grab all the text given under a .
Now it returns the text as well as the 
I want to learn the quickest way to too this, and format it by a comma.

Now I alternatively code it by commanding to grab every  separately.
But I want to grab more then 20 items, so I want to find a quicker way.
And also learn from it: D

I tried switching in find and find_all as well by adding get_text at the end.
They all give an error

```
        kenmerken = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
        details = kenmerken.find_all ('div', {'class':'detail-tab-content kenmerken'})
        try:
            tr = details[0].find_all ('td', {'class': 'value'})
        except IndexError:
            size_space = 'Unknown'
        print(tr)
```

Result:

```
    [<td class="value">
            Herenhuis

    </td>, <td class="value">
            2008
    </td>, <td class="value">
            250 m²
    </td>, <td class="value">
            -    
    </td>, <td class="value">
            -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
            -
    </td>, <td class="value">
            -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        5
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        Ja
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        -
    </td>, <td class="value">
        Ja
    </td>, <td class="value">
        3.627
    </td>, <td class="value">
        64
    </td>]
[<td class="value">
```

Answer (score 1):

In your try block `tr` will be a list of `td` elements. If you want the `td .text` you need to iterate the list e.g. use a list comprehension. I have swopped `find_all` for `select` - both return lists.

```
tds_values = [td.text for td in details[0].select('td.value')]
```

If you intend to loop `details` as well then use:

```
for detail in details:
    tds_values = [td.text for td in detail.select('td.value')]
```

if you want a comma separated string

```
tds_values = ','.join([td.text.strip() for td in detail.select('td.value')])
```

Comment: Oke thanks! that works!
is there also a way to get rid of the spaces?
for my old code i used this:
(separator='\n', strip=True)

but it doenst work anymore

Comment: is there a way to strip the spaces and add a comma?

Comment: Herenhuis, 2008, 250 m², -,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,-,-,-,-,-,Ja,-,-,Ja,3.627,64

something like this. it goes in to a csv file.

Comment: changed it to this : tr = ','.join([td.text.strip() for td in details[0].select('td.value')])

works fine!

Comment: yeah... for the top version.